# Using dynamic configurations with modelfield form validation in django

Tags: django, postgresql, validation, django-models, django-admin

I have setup a model called Configuration, which contains configurable details, such as `maximum_stake`, and registered this in admin.py so that an admin can change them on the fly.

Most of my validation is done through the natural ModelForm validation, but when I tried to do this with the dynamically changing constraints from the Configuration model, Postgre complained about the relation not existing (so I was unable to create a migration to build or edit the Configuration model table). However, even after making these changes the database is unhappy. Is there another way to do this?

```
# models.py

class Investor(models.Model):
    stake = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)

class InvestorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stake = forms.DecimalField(help_text="The income stake as a percentage (0.00% - 8.00%)", validators=[
        MinValueValidator(0, f'Stake must be between 0.00%% and {getConfig(ConfigData.MAXIMUM_STAKE)}.00%%'),
        MaxValueValidator(getConfig(ConfigData.MAXIMUM_STAKE),
                          f'Stake must be between 0.00%% and {getConfig(ConfigData.MAXIMUM_STAKE)}.00%%')
    ])

    class Meta:
        model = Investor
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ModelForm's Clean method to check for validation when using dynamic constraints:

```
 def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        current_stake = cleaned_data.get("stake")
        minimum_stake = 0
        maximum_stake = ConfigData.objects.first().maximum_stake #get the object from database where the configuration is saved dynamically here

        if not(current_stake > minimum_stake and current_stake <= maximum_stake):
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far or raise error
            raise forms.ValidationError(f'Stake must be between {minimum_stake}%% and {maximum_stake}.00%%')
```

Or you can create a custom Django Field as follow:

```
from django import forms

class CustomStakeField(forms.Field):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return float(value)

    def validate(self, value):
        """Check if value lies within range"""
        super().validate(value)
        minimum_stake = 0
        maximum_stake = ConfigData.objects.first().maximum_stake #get the object from database where the configuration is saved dynamically here

            if not(current_stake > minimum_stake and current_stake <= maximum_stake):
                # Only do something if both fields are valid so far or raise error
                raise forms.ValidationError(f'Stake must be between {minimum_stake}%% and {maximum_stake}.00%%')
```

Then simply use this in the Model Form as :

`stake = CustomStakeField()`